# Return a series of DT::datatables within a list in knitted HTML document

Tags: html, r, list, r-markdown, dt

I have a function that returns a series of tables. I want to return them all as a DT::datatable. However, I cannot get R to return these tables when they are in a list. They appear in the RMarkdown file, but not in the knitted HTML file. Is it possible to get the tables to appear in the HTML doc?

```
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---
```

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(tidyverse)
```

```
myfunc <- function(dataset){
  
  return_list <- list()
  
  mytab <- DT::datatable(dataset)
  
  return_list$mytab <- mytab
  
  return(return_list)
}

myfunc(mtcars)
```

---

The table appears in the RMarkdown file:

[image: Table in RMD file]

But does not appear in the knitted HTML file:

[image: Table does not appear in HTML doc]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two ways to do this:

If you know the keys in advance, just call it with the key

```
myfunc(mtcars)$mytab
```

If you are planning to make a longer list and want to print all of the tables in the list, use `tagList` from `{htmltools}`

```
htmltools::tagList(myfunc(mtcars))
```